# How to create xml for execution results using Junit5 in a maven project?

Tags: java, maven, junit5

I want to generate the test results in xml format for the executed tests in a maven project using Junit5. I have read that it was automatically generated in Junit4 but Junit5 doesn't support it. Can anyone suggest any way to create the xml reports for executed tests in Junit5 for a Maven project ?

Comment: Bottom of this page might have what you are looking for: https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/junit-platform.html

Comment: I have a lot of tests running in project. I want to create testresults.xml using Junit5. Please explain a bit how the surefire plugin cab be used to create the xml ?